# Discord.py Rewrite. How to create a command to add roles?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm attempting to create a bot that allows users to add themselves to a role (Looking for group) by typing .lfg (prefix = .). I've tried looking through the API Reference and still don't understand how to use `discord.Member.add_roles`
Here is my code so far:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def lfg(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    test = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Looking for group")
    print(test)
    await discord.Member.add_roles(test,reason=None,atomic=True)
    await ctx.send("Role added")
```

Comment: Okay, so what happened with the code that you tried, and how does it differ from what you expected / hoped for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be member.add_roles() as you've defined ctx.author to member and pass_context is not needed

```py
@client.command()
async def lfg(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    test = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Looking for group")
    print(test)
    await member.add_roles(test,reason=None,atomic=True)
    await ctx.send("Role added")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i don't know why i couldn't find this on the documentation

Comment: np, python docs are pretty much not suitable for beginners always haha